# Detecting weak blobs in a noise image

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection

I have an image which may contain some blobs. The blobs can be any size, and some will yield a very strong signal, while others are very weak. In this question I will focus on the weak ones because they are the difficult ones to detect.

Here is an example with 4 blobs.

[image]

The blob at (480, 180) is the most difficult one to detect. By running a Gaussian filter followed by an opening operation increases the contrast a bit, but not a lot:

[image]

The tricky part of this problem is that the natural noise in the background will result in (many) pixels which have a stronger signal than the blob I want to detect. What makes the blob a blob is that it's either a large area with an average increase in intensity, (or a small area with a very strong increase in intensity (not relevant here)).

**How can I include this spacial information in order to detect my blob?**

It is obvious that I first needs to filter the image with a Gaussian and/or median filter in order to incorporate the nearby region of each pixel into each single pixel value. However, no amount of blurring is enough to make it easy to segment the blobs from the background.

EDIT: **Regarding thresholding:** Thresholding is very temping, but also problematic by itself. I do not have a region of "pure background" and the larger a blob is, the weaker the signal can be - while still being detectable.

I should also not that the typical image will not have any blobs at all, but just be pure background.

Comment: Try thresholding, then labelling connected components, then a morphological opening to get rid of the smaller components (noise).

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean I will clarify this in the question. I find (initial) thresholding problematic because I do not know which threshold to use. 1)  I do not know a region which is guaranteed to contain background. 2) If a blob is larger, it's signal can be weaker.

Comment: Are you just looking for positive identification and location of blobs or do you need an accurate size measurement as well?

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear just positive identification and (approx) location

Comment: If there are other (cases) that you are trying to identify (ie a situation where a blob is lower values than background, or a single pixel high intensity spike, it is very helpful for us if you post images of those as well...)

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out/ deciding on a strategy?

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear Maybe. Unfortunately I am currently distracted, but will get back to it in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a h-minima transform. It removes any minima under the height of h and increases the height of all other throughs by h. It's defined as the morphological reconstruction of an erosion increased by the height h. Here's the results with h = 35:

[image: after h-minima transform]

It should be a lot easier to manipulate. It also needs a input like segmentation. The difference is that this is more robust. Underestimating h by a relatively large number will only bring you back closer to the original problem image instead of failing completely.

You could try to characterize the background noise to get an estimate, assuming that whatever your application is would have a relatively constant amount of it.

Note that one blue dot between the two large bottom blobs. Even further processing is needed. You could try continuing with the morphology. Something that I have found to work in some 'ink-blot' segmentation cases like this is running through every connected component, calculating their convex hulls and finally the union of all the convex hulls in the image. It usually makes further morphological operations much easier and provides a good estimate for the label.

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting. I'll play around with it

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you can see your gaussian filter size (those little circles), then your filter width is too small.  Although terribly expensive, try bumping up the radius on your gaussian, it should continue to improve your results up to its radius matching the radius of the smallest object you are trying to find.

Following that (heavy gaussian), I would do a peak search across the whole image.  Cut out any peaks that are too low, and or have too little contrast to the nearest valley/ background.

Don't be afraid to split this into two isolated processing pipelines: ie one filtration and extraction for low contrast spread out blobs, and a completely different one to isolate high contrast spikes (much much easier to find).  That being said, a high contrast spike "should" survive even a pretty aggressive filter.  Another thing to keep in mind is iterative subtraction, if there are some blobs that can be found easily from the get go, pull them out of the image and then do a stretch (but be careful as you can make the image be whatever you want it to be with too much stretching)

Comment: Thanks. First of all, increasing the Gaussian filter by a lot does improve the situation. However, how can I do I approach this when I don't really have a "smallest object"? My smallest objects are very contrast dependent. If the contrast is huge I can detect objects smaller than a pixel (one or two pixels will just be very bright), and if the contrast is poor (like in this case) the object obviously needs to be much larger to be visible.

Comment: Well, I have to assume that your small objects (if detectable) have very high contrast (or else they would be indistinguishable from your background noise).

Comment: Although it is nice to set a guassian filter to your target size, really at the end of the day, it just needs to be big enough to kill your noise, so maybe run some analysis of your worst case noise and set your gaussian filter based on that.  a gaussian filter should never make your object harder to find until it surpasses its size.

Comment: You could do an iterative approach.  Where you go through first pass and pull any objects you can see (super bright high contrast).  Then apply an iteratively larger and larger gaussian filters until you are satisfied that you are left with little more than noise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try an iterative approach using thresholding and edge detection:

Start with a very high threshold (say 90% signal), then run a canny filter (or any binary edge filter you like) on the thresholded image.  Count and store the number of pixels (edge pixels) generated.

Proceed to repeat this step for lower and lower thresholds.  At a certain point you are going to see a massive spike in edges detected (ie your cool textured background).  Then pull back the threshold a little higher and run closing and floodfill on your resulting edge image.